# Printing the objects in the array

Tags: java

I'm not sure how to print the objects in the array. the print(); method is called from a different class file. Can somebody tell me if i'm using the .print method correctly or getting the objects from the array correctly?

```
public class PFArray {
    private int top;
    int n;
    Place[] storage;
    Place p;

    class PFArray_Exception extends Exception {
    }

    public PFArray(int arraylength) {
        n = arraylength;
        storage = new Place[n];
        top = 0;
    }

    public void flush() {
        storage = null;
        top = 0;
    }

    public boolean is_full() {
        if (top != n) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int space_left() {
        int space_left = n - top;
        return space_left;
    }

    public void add_item(Place p) throws PFArray_Exception {
        if (top == n) {
            throw new PFArray_Exception();
        } else {
            storage[top] = p;
            top = top + 1;
        }
    }

    public int position_in_array(Place p) throws PFArray_Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < top; i++) {
            if (storage[i].equals(p)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        throw new PFArray_Exception();
    }

    public void remove_item(int n) throws PFArray_Exception {
        if (top != n) {

            top = top - 1;
        } else {
            throw new PFArray_Exception();
        }
    }

    public void unsafe_remove_item(int n) {
        if (top != n) {
            top = top - 1;
        }
    }

    public int unsafe_position_in_array(Place p) {
        for (int i = 0; i < top; i++) {
            if (storage[i].equals(p)) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void print_all() {
        System.out.print(n);
        while (p != null) {
            p.print();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whether you use it correctly or not, depends on what it has to do. Anyway, this is wrong: while (p != null) {
       p.print(); 
   }
if p is not null, this will cause an infinite loop, and will crash your application

Comment: oops i fixed that already, the function is to print 'Places' that i've stored in the array, how do i do that?

Comment: never mind i got it thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

## Use proven solutions

Your code tries to re-implement the behavior of an existing collection. Use `ArrayList<Place>` or `LinkedList<Place>` instead. Browse for [numerous examples on the web](https://www.google.ru/search?q=ArrayList%20example&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=UV-OVdndB4ycsAH5t7WoBA)

## Implement toString in `Place` class

This will help you to easily convert your `Place` to a readable string, [look here](https://www.google.ru/search?q=ArrayList%20example&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=UV-OVdndB4ycsAH5t7WoBA#q=java%20tostring%20implement)

If you still want to print out an array, use `ArrayUtils.toString(storage)`. But you will need to implement `toString()` as well:

```
public class Place {
 @Override
 public String toString() {
    return String.format("<PUT YOU FORMAT HERE>");
 }
}
```